# How to make parallel request in Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a button which sync from my external api some data to my android device database, that data is get from two different APIs.

Which would be the best way to make the call to both of them and wait for the response from both APIs and then insert the data to the database?

My Sercice looks like this:

```
@GET("api/prodotti/fornitori")
fun getFornitori(): Call<List<Fornitori>>

@GET("api/prodotti/pv")
fun getPuntiVendita(): Call<List<PuntiVendita>
```

Till now i was doing two calls one after another, but at that point i was showing "Sync" snackbar twice and saying twice that the data has been saved, while i would do it once for both API calls...

The call for one of the APIs was like this:

```
           val urlServer = preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences.getString("server", "http://127.0.0.1/")!!
val snackSincronizzo = Snackbar.make(
    requireView(),
    "Sincronizzo le impostazioni...",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
)
snackSincronizzo.show()
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(urlServer)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .build()
val service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
val callFornitori = service.getFornitori()
callFornitori.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Fornitori>> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<List<Fornitori>>,
        response: Response<List<Fornitori>>
    ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val fornitori = response.body()!!
            if (fornitori.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (fornitore in fornitori) {
                    corpoViewModel.insertFornitori(fornitore)
                }
                val callPuntiVendita = service.getPuntiVendita()
                callPuntiVendita.enqueue(object : Callback<List<PuntiVendita>> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<List<PuntiVendita>>,
                        response: Response<List<PuntiVendita>>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val puntiVendita = response.body()!!
                            if (puntiVendita.isNotEmpty()) {
                                for (puntoVendita in puntiVendita) {
                                    corpoViewModel.insertPuntiVendita(puntoVendita)
                                }
                            }
                            customSnack(requireView(), "Impostazioni sincronizzati con successo!", false)
                            snackSincronizzo.dismiss()
                        }else {
                            snackSincronizzo.dismiss()
                            customSnack(requireView(), "Errore durante la sincronizzazione!",true)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(
                        call: Call<List<PuntiVendita>>,
                        t: Throwable
                    ) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
            }
            snackSincronizzo.dismiss()
        }else {
            snackSincronizzo.dismiss()
            customSnack(requireView(), "Errore durante la sincronizzazione!",true)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Fornitori>>, t: Throwable) {
        snackSincronizzo.dismiss()
        customSnack(requireView(), "Errore durante la sincronizzazione!",true)
    }
})
```

So how can i change it to make both getFornitori and getPuntiVendita and get one callback with both data?

Comment: You want to use coroutines or RxJava?

Comment: @KishanMaurya Coroutines will be better but i'd can use even RxJava

Comment: I have added Using zip operator in RxJava. Try this & let me know

Answer (score 1):

In Rx, You can try this.

Change your service class to `Single` instead of `Call` like this

```
@GET("api/prodotti/fornitori")
fun getFornitori(): Single<List<Fornitori>>

@GET("api/prodotti/pv")
fun getPuntiVendita(): Single<List<PuntiVendita>
```

And call it like this. We can use Zip operator in RxJava to achieve this

```
private fun getBothData() {
        val fornitorList = service.getFornitori()
        val puntiVenditaList = service.getPuntiVendita()
        val dispose =
            Single.zip<List<Fornitori>, List<PuntiVendita>, Pair<List<Fornitori>, List<PuntiVendita>>>(
                fornitorList,
                puntiVenditaList,
                BiFunction { t1, t2 -> Pair(t1, t2) }
            ).subscribe(
                {
                   val firstApiData = it.first
                   val secondApiData = it.second
                },
                {
                    //Handle Error Part
                })
    }
```

Add all RxJava Dependecies &  `addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` in retrofit builder.

Approach 2 in Kotlin using coroutine

Service class

```
  @GET("api/prodotti/fornitori")
    suspend fun getFornitori(): List<Fornitori>
    
    @GET("api/prodotti/pv")
    suspend fun getPuntiVendita(): List<PuntiVendita>
```

Change your method

```
suspend fun getBothData(): Pair<List<Fornitori>, List<PuntiVendita>>> {
            var data: Pair<List<Fornitori>, List<PuntiVendita>> = Pair(listOf(), listOf())
            coroutineScope {
                val firstAPIData = async { service.getFornitori()}.await()
                val seconfAPIData = async { service.getPuntiVendita()}.await()
                data = Pair(firstAPIData, seconfAPIData)
                return@coroutineScope
            }
            return data
        }
```

Now from calling the place

```
GlobalScope.launch {
            val bothData = getBothData()
            val firstApiData = bothData.first
            val secondApiData = bothData.second
        }
```

Comment: i get the following error: `Unable to create call adapter for io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single<java.util.List<it.gabtamagnini.visualstock.models.Fornitori>>`

Comment: I've added the `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` and `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'` in my grandle